# Set input class using JS

Tags: javascript, class

Got the following JS code.

```
<script language="javascript">
fields = 0;
pNR = 0;
err=0;
function addInput() {
    if (fields != 40) {
        var firstInput = document.createElement("input");
        var secondInput = document.createElement("input");

        firstInput.type = secondInput.type = "text";
        firstInput.name = "firstfield" + pNR;
        secondInput.name = "secondfield" + pNR;


        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        text.appendChild(firstInput);
        text.appendChild(secondInput);
        text.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        fields += 1;
        pNR += 1;
    } else ...

</script>
```

I want to set a class for each  tag created. 
The class should be the name of the field and `"required":`class="firstfield0 required"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className), it gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

```
firstInput.className = "firstfield0 required";
```

Comment: Uhh, I was using firstInput.class . Problem solved. Thank you!